# How To Create a iPad Device Difference Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to create programmatically multiple `devices` screen `sizes` for multiple UI differences on sizes. Below code I am using for different `sizes` within condition but `iPad` screen sizes not showing full screen. Help me to create full screen sizes within different device iPad.

My Code Below :

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        // The device is an iPad and iPad mini running iOS 3.2 or later.
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 1366) {

            // iPad, iPad 2, iPad Mini
            splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768,result.height);
            [splashImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default-Portrait.png" ]];
            activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(145, 240, 30, 30);
        }
        if(result.height == 2008) {

            // iPad Air, iPad Mini Retina
            splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1536,result.height);
            [splashImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default-Portrait@2x.png" ]];
            activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(145, 240, 30, 30);
        }
    }
```

Comment: anushhka - I have one doubt , in future if any new devices arrive in market you add the any additional condition for your concept, it is correct ...

Comment: are you using autolayout..

Comment: what do you mean by ipad screen size not showing full screen ? Could you pls provide more info ?Also why dont you use results.width instead of hardcoding the width value.

Comment: I guest you should just add splash.contenMode = .ScaleAspectFill

Comment: FYI - All iPad screens are 1024x768 except for the iPad Pro. BTW - what you are trying to do is a bad idea. How are you going to handle your app running in multitasking mode on newer iPads?

Answer (score 0):

I Feel there is something wrong in your approach.

-Use Autoresizing feature ,which expands the screen based on screen resolution.

- IOS will automatically picks up 2X or 3X image. No need of explicit code for  2x Image.

-Use this in all places. Not required to mention 2X
  [splashImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default-Portrait.png" ]];